# Formatting asp.net label when the value is sourced from a query string

Tags: asp.net, format, query-string, label

Afternoon all.

A very simple one for you today from thicky Rich.

I have a label I want to display as a lovely number format i.e. {0:N0}

Now, this label text equates to a query string value.

How do I go about formatting a label's text from a query string value in one fell swoop?

I have tried this

`lblTotalPurchQS.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}",Request.QueryString["totalpurchasequantity"].ToString());`

but with little success.

Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ToString` on the incoming query string parameter, but convert it to an `int` first:

```
lblTotalPurchQS.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", int.Parse(Request.QueryString["totalpurchasequantity"]));
```

Note:

The above is not safe code. First, the conversion may fail with a conversion exception. You should also be HTML escaping the output, in case of XSS.

This is better:

```
int totalPurchaseQuantity;

if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["totalpurchasequantity"], out totalPurchaseQuantity))
{
    lblTotalPurchQS.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(String.Format("{0:N0}", totalPurchaseQuantity);
}
```

Comment: Top stuff Oded - thanks for that and the advice re. conversion exceptions.